# browser-sync with module loaders (angular2 + systemjs)

Tags: css, angular, browser-sync, systemjs

I'm building a single page app with angular2 and systemjs. I'm also using gulp to compile from typescript to javascript, because I don't want to make the typescript modules public.

I am also using a gulp watcher and gulp browser-sync.

Because angular2 is web component based and uses a module loader for injection at runtime, all the templates and styles are also injected at runtime.

The head-tag

`<head>...</head>`

doesnt contain any css files, because angular is applying the styles of each component at the components dom element at runtime.

Because of that, browser-sync has to reload the whole page if it detects some changes.

**Does anybody know of a solution to have a browser synchronization when using angular 2 without having the whole page to reload?**

Here is my gulp task which is piping the modified css to browsersync:

```
gulp.task('copy:css', ['copy:thirdparty-css', 'copy:css-global'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(paths.scssSourceApp)
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssDestFolderApp));

    if (development()) {
        stream.pipe(browserSync.stream());
    }
    return stream;
});
```

Here is the browser-sync init and the gulp watcher:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "https://localhost:44387"
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch([paths.scssSourceApp, 
    paths.scssSourceGlobal, 
    paths.appSource, 
    paths.templateSource], 
    ['copy:templates','copy:css','compile:ts']);
});
```